# toggle visiiblity of SVG dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, visibility

How can I toggle the visibility of an svg dynamically, with JQuery or otherwise?

I have this SVG (as a marker icon in a Leaflet map)

```
<svg class= "icon icon14"><use xlink:href="#marker"/></svg>
```

..but the basic JQuery function I am used to doesn't seem to work (the toggle should be triggered by a map zoom event):

```
if ...  $(".icon").css("visibility", "visible");
else $(".icon").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

I tried triggering the JQuery function form a button click event as well, with the same (non)result:

```
$("#zoomin").on("click", function () {
   console.log("clicked");
   if (map.getZoom() === 14){
       console.log("zoom=14");
       $(".icon14").css("visibility", "visible");

    }else{
       $(".icon14").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }  
  });
```

Comment: Can you give a more specific example? Using JQuery to set visibility does work on SVG, which seems to suggest your problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: That looks like it should work - does it work on a button click event instead of a map zoom event? I.e. `<button onclick="$(".icon').css('visibility', 'hidden')">`?

Comment: I added a click event to the zoom buttons, with the same result.  the problem may be related to Leaflet functions- I am adding a geoJSON layer, with divIcons that refernce the SVGs..I have been having issues with this for a few days now: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172005/leaflet-jquery-cannot-add-or-remove-class-to-divicon-marker

Comment: FWIW, see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/43534L47/) for simple JQuery toggle visibility example with SVG.